# Auto Kill Shell Command & get output

Tags: linux, shell, redis

Hi I am running an shell command & auto killing it after 10 seconds using an shell script having content :

( cmdpid=$BASHPID; (sleep 10; kill $cmdpid) & exec redis-cli --latency )

This is working & killing. How do I change the shell script to actually get the o/p of command after the command is killed.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you can simply capture the output of your program with redirecting stdout and stderr to a file and later kill the programm after the sleep, like this:

```
ping stackoverflow.com >/tmp/ping.log 2>&1 & sleep 10 && kill $!
```

$! is the PID of the most recent background command.

This way you don't need to kill the whole bash process like I understand you're doing in your script.

Comment: Wat if another background gets started after my script , so that other process will be killed instead of this process. How do I make sure so kill this specific process?

Comment: You can store the pid in a variable:

    ping stackoverflow.com >/tmp/ping.log 2>&1 & PINGPID=$! && sleep 10 && kill $PINGPID